# Does using Data Model in Excel instead of regular tables and ranges affect performance?

Tags: excel, powerpivot

Would it be more efficient for excel to rely on a data model rather than on ranges and tables to generate interactive dashboards?

If it would improve the performance, on another hand, I am wondering how easy it is to update these reports when all the data is stored in the data model instead of spreadsheets. Right now, as I can see, the data is manually inserted into spreadsheets and then formatted using a macro. So, the analyst generating it does not have the security rights to connect excel to the database.

Anyway, just curious about it. Wondering if it's worth my time learning how to use a data model as I only have a very basic understanding of it. Was rather considering to spend more time on VBA, but people also say that tableau is better. That is another topic though :)

Answer (score 0):

Row limit in Excel tables is **1,048,576**, in the data model it's **1,999,999,997**. So for *tiny data* Excel tables and VBA is just fine. But if you want to enter the world of *big data*, you'll have to get your hands dirty. And btw., it's the same topic with Tableau.

Inserting data manually into spreadsheets and then formatting it using a macro is just rubbish.